# How can I transform only the top level nodes of an xml file in scala (not the descendants)

Tags: xml, scala, transform

I have some xml where there is an `<id/>` node at the top level, and also inside descendant nodes. Is there a way for me to change the value at the top level and not at the lower levels?

Sample input is

```
val inputXml = 
  <top>
    <id>123</id>
    <a>
      <id>innerId</id>
    </a>
    <b>other info</b>
    <c>
      <id>444</id>
    </c>
  </top>
```

The output I'd like to see is:

```
val expectedOutputXml =
  <top>
    <id>999</id>
    <a>
      <id>innerId</id>
    </a>
    <b>other info</b>
    <c>
      <id>444</id>
    </c>
  </top>
```

I've tried using RewriteRule like this:

```
import scala.xml.transform.{RewriteRule, RuleTransformer}
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node, NodeSeq}

def changeTopId(root:Node, newId:String) = {

  val dontChg = root \ "_" filter {e => List("a", "b").contains(e.label)}

  object t1 extends RewriteRule{
    override def transform(n: Seq[Node]): Seq[Node] = n match {
      case e:Elem if dontChg.contains(e) => e
      case e:Elem if e.label == "id" => <id>{newId}</id>
      case other => other
    }
  }
  object changeTopOne extends RuleTransformer(t1)

  changeTopOne(root)
}
```

But it affects all `<id/>` nodes, resulting in:

```
scala> changeTopId(inputXml, "999")
res1: scala.xml.Node =
<top>
    <id>999</id>
    <a>
      <id>999</id>
    </a>
    <b>other info</b>
    <c>
      <id>999</id>
    </c>
  </top>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't need Rewrite Rule.
Here's a 5 line solution.

```
val xs = (inputXml \ "_") map {
  case e: Elem if e.label == "id" => <id>999</id>
  case other => other
}

inputXml.copy(child=xs)
```

And the resulting value (formatted manually)

```
scala.xml.Elem =
<top>
    <id>999</id>
    <a>
        <id>innerId</id>
    </a>
    <b>other info</b>
    <c>
        <id>444</id>
    </c>
</top>
```